# Select single key whose value is an array in multidimensional JSON object and loop through that array

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays, json

Edit: My issue is that when giving the function `appendAllComments` the parameter `subid`, when I alert `subid` it says for example `77` which indeed exists within the JSON object. So:

```
global_save_json.input == global_save_json.subid == global_save_json.77 (?) or "77"
```

yet it's returning `undefined` for whatever reason? Is this a number vs. string issue or something?

---

I need to select a key of the `comments` object and then loop through the array.

From `fresh_posts.php`:

```
{ 
    "posts":{
        "5": {
            "id":"5",
            "image":"link.jpg",
            "submitter":"4322309",
            "views":"3"
        },
        "2": {
            "id":"2",
            "image":"link.jpg",
            "submitter":"4322309",
            "views":"5"
        }
    },

    "comments":{
        "2": [{
            "id":"1",
            "submitter":"submitter",
            "time":"2435657",
            "comment":"comment",
            "score":"10",
            "postid":"2"
        },
        {
            "id":"2",
            "submitter":"submitter",
            "time":"2435657",
            "comment":"comment",
            "score":"10",
            "postid":"2"
        }
    ],
        "5": [{
            "id":"3",
            "submitter":"submitter",
            "time":"2435657",
            "comment":"comment",
            "score":"10",
            "postid":"5"
        }]
    }
}
```

Initially  have:

```
$.getJSON('fresh_posts.php',function(data){
    global_save_json = data.comments;
```

Now I need to use that `global_save_json` once again later down the track.

```
$('.main').on('click', '.new-comments', function(e) {

      var fullid = e.target.id;
      var subid = fullid.substring(8); // subid = number like 75

      function appendAllComments(input) {

        for (var commentList in global_save_json.input) {
          $.each(commentList, function(index, c) {
            // i need to set variables, i.e. var id = the value of "id" key in the object in the array of comments
          })
        }
      }

      appendAllComments(subid);

 })
```

I've tried to re-use an earlier for loop but it's not working, I'm stuck - see comment inside loop for what I'm trying to do

Comment: `data.comments['2'].forEach(function() {...`

Comment: The click function isn't within the `$.getJSON` though

Comment: What do you mean by "its not working?" Any error messages? It might be an ASYNC problem... maybe trying to click before the data is loaded? Have a look at jQuery promises: [jQuery Promises](https://api.jquery.com/promise/)

Comment: It shouldn't be an async problem as the data is already saved to the `global_save_json` variable. There's no errors, it's just not doing what I want it to do...

Comment: can you confirm that there is data in the global_save_json? `console.log(global_save_json)`
Also, why global_save_json.input? Wouldn't it be just global_save_json?

Comment: There is as I do a promise thing which uses it on load. `.input` is so it can select the key within the `comments` object, right??

Comment: Not sure... what if you used this instead:
`$.each(global_save_json, function(commentsListIndex, commentsList) {
    $.each(commentList, function(index, c) {
        ....
}`
And your values would be c.id, etc.

Comment: Yeah, I have that as a previous one (append all comments for all posts). For this one I only want to append all comments for a single post (linked by ID).